# Bootstrap 4 Form Check - Change Order of Optons left to> right and top to bottom to top to bottom and left right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple Bootstrap form showing a checkbox with 13 options - the options comprise of the following:

`Urban Plans`
`Commercial Entity`
`Cultural Approval`
`Education Sector`
`Hospitality`
`Industrial Design`
`Interiors Art`
`Leisure/ Sporting`
`Residential Care`
`Retail Space`
`Seniors Living Care`
`Student Housing`
`Warehouse`

It currently looks like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-6">

</div><!-- /.col-md-6-->

    
    <div class="col-md-6">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <th scope="col">Customer Sectors</th>
                        </thead>
    <tr>
    
    
    
    <td>
    
                               
                 <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Urban Plans">Urban Plans                            </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Commercial Entity">Commercial Entity                            </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Cultural Approval">Cultural Approval                            </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Education Sector">Education Sector                          </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Hospitality">Hospitality                            </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Industrial Design">Industrial Design                            </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Interiors Art">Interiors Art                            </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Leisure/ Sporting" checked="checked">Leisure/ Sporting                          </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Residential Care">Residential Care                          </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Retail Space">Retail Space                          </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Seniors Living Care">Seniors Living Care                            </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Student Housing" checked="checked">Student Housing                          </label>
                                                        <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Warehouse">Warehouse                            </label>
                                        
            
    
    
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  
    </div><!-- /.col-md-6-->

</div><!-- /.row-->
```

The values for the checkbox are retrieved from a database so they are dynamically generated.  As you can see the options are displayed from left to right then top to bottom for each row.

Here's a screenshot in case the snippet doesn't display correctly:

[image]

We would like to change it so the list is displayed from top to bottom then left to right, so it would appear on the web page like this:

Urban Plans                    Leisure/ Sporting

Commercial Entity              Residential Care

Cultural Approval              Retail Space

Education Sector               Seniors Living Care

Hospitality                    Student Housing

Industrial Design              Warehouse

Interiors Art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) to do this. You can create a class for the container for your checkboxes, and specify:

- how many columns to show
- the minimum size for the columns

So for example, the class below will display the checkboxes in 2 columns of a minimum 200px width (once the screen gets too small for the columns to be displayed side-by-side, the columns will get stacked)

```
.mycolumns{
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
       -moz-column-count: 2;
            column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-width: 200px;
       -moz-column-width: 200px;
            column-width: 200px;
}
```

Of course, you can change this to be whatever number of columns and width you want.

**Working Snippet:**

```css
.mycolumns{
  -webkit-columns: 2 200px;
     -moz-columns: 2 200px;
          columns: 2 200px;
}
/* put each checkbox on a separate line */
.mycolumns label { display:block}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>This is your first col-md-6</p>
  </div><!-- /.col-md-6-->


  <div class="col-md-6">

      <h2>Customer Sectors</h2>
    <div class="mycolumns">
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Urban Plans">Urban Plans                            </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Commercial Entity">Commercial Entity                            </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Cultural Approval">Cultural Approval                            </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Education Sector">Education Sector                          </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Hospitality">Hospitality                            </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Industrial Design">Industrial Design                            </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Interiors Art">Interiors Art                            </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Leisure/ Sporting" checked="checked">Leisure/ Sporting                          </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Residential Care">Residential Care                          </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Retail Space">Retail Space                          </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Seniors Living Care">Seniors Living Care                            </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Student Housing" checked="checked">Student Housing                          </label>
      <label class="checkbox-inline-contacts">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="clientSectors" name="clientSectors[]" value="Warehouse">Warehouse                            </label>


    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.col-md-6-->

</div>
<!-- /.row-->
```

Comment: @user982124 Would that solution work for you? The only way to change items from being displayed across-then-down (which is the standard layout) is to use some form of columns. This is the quickest & easiest way, but let us know if it will work or if its not suitable for you.